# How to retrieve user profile to the frontend | PassportJs

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to log in a user using Passport Js (Google Auth), I configured Passport Js and i'm getting the user profile in my console, but I didn't know how to show the user profile in frontend, the **configure for `PassportJs` goes like:**

```
passport.use(
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: "",
          clientSecret: "",
          callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
          scope: ["profile", "email"],
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) =>  {
          // find current user in UserModel
            const currentUser = await User.findOne({
                    googleId: profile.id
            });
            
          // create new user if the database doesn't have this user
            if (!currentUser) {
              const newUser = await new User({
                googleId: profile.id,
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                displayName: profile.displayName,
                firstName: profile.name.givenName,
                lastName: profile.name.familyName,
                profilePic: profile.photos[0].value,
              }).save();
              if (newUser) {
                done(null, newUser);
              }
            }
            console.log("CURRNT USER: ", currentUser);
            done(null, currentUser);
        }
      )
    );
    
    // serialize the user.id to save in the cookie session
    // so the browser will remember the user when login
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
      });

      passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id)
          .then(user => {
            done(null, user);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            done(new Error("Failed to deserialize an user"));
          });
      });
```

**And in the `Auth.js` route:**

```
// when login is successful, retrieve user info
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      error: false,
      message: "succesfull",
      user: req.user,
      cookies: req.cookies
    });
  } else {
        res.status(403).json({ error: true, message: "Not Authorized" });
    }
});

// auth with google
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", ["profile", "email"]))

// redirect to home page after successfully login via google
router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/",
      failureRedirect: "/login/failed"
    })
);
```

I'm using Context to let the app knows if the user is logged in or not.

**`Login.jsx:` Normal Logging Using express and Mongodb **

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/login", {
        email: userRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value,
      });
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE" });
      setError(true)
    }
  };

//Now I tried this code to log in a user using Google Auth but it didn't work
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/login/success`, {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      },
    })
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" })
      .then((response) => {
        
        if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
        throw new Error('failed to authenticate user');
      })
      .then((responseJson) => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: responseJson.data });
        

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE" });
        console.error("Failed to authenticate user", error)
      });
  }, []);


  const google = () => {
    window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback", "_self");
  };
```

The full code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-mountain-e5t9d4?file=/api/routes/auth.js

Answer (score 0):

let me share with you the perfect code.

**passportStratergy.js**

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const User = require('../model/user'); 
const { USER_TYPES } = require('../constants/authConstant');

const googlePassportStrategy = passport => {
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
    cb(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, cb) {
    cb(null, user);
  });

  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACKURL
  }, async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    if (profile){
      let userObj = {
        'username':profile.displayName,
        'ssoAuth': { 'googleId': profile.id },
        'email': profile.emails !== undefined ? profile.emails[0].value : '',
        'password':'',
        'userType':USER_TYPES.User
      };
      let found = await User.findOne(User,{ 'email': userObj.email });
      if (found) {
        const id = found.id;
        await User.updateOne(User, { _id :id }, userObj);
      }
      else {
        await User.create(User, userObj);
      }
      let user = await User.findOne(User,{ 'ssoAuth.googleId':profile.id });
      return done(null, user);
    }
    return done(null, null);
  }
  ));

};
module.exports = { googlePassportStrategy };
```

**auth.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');

const { socialLogin } = require('../services/auth');

router.get('/auth/google/error', (req, res) => {
  res.loginFailed({ message:'Login Failed' });
});

router.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google', { 
  scope: ['profile', 'email'],
  session:false 
}));

router.get('/auth/google/callback',
  (req,res,next)=>{
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/auth/google/error' }, async (error, user , info) => {
      if (error){
        return res.send({ message:error.message });
      }
      if (user){
        try {
          //let result = await socialLogin(user.email); 
          // here your business logic for login user.
          return res.send({
            data: result.data,
            message:'Login Successful' 
          });
        } catch (error) {
          return res.send({ message: error.message });
        }
      }
    })(req,res,next);
  }); 

module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { googlePassportStrategy } = require('./passportStrategy');
googlePassportStrategy(passport);
```

Comment: What about the frontend? how can I call this code in the frontend and fetch the user profile?

Comment: call  /auth/google API by fetch it will give you the user profile if user login successful